# Fastest Search Through Random Nested Data

Tags: python, algorithm

```
[
   [
      [2,33,64,276,1],
      [234,5,234,7,34,36,7,2],
      []
   ]
   [
      [2,4,5]
   ]
   .
   .
   .
   etc
]
```

I'm not looking for an exact solution to this, as the structure above is just an example. I'm trying to search for an ID that can be nested several levels deep within a group of IDs ordered randomly.

Currently I'm just doing a linear search which takes a few minutes to get a result when each of the deepest levels has a couple hundred of IDs. I was wondering if anyone could suggest a faster algorithm for searching through multiple levels of random data? I am doing this in Python if that matters.

Note: The IDs are always at the deepest level and the number of levels is consistent for each branch down. Not sure if that matters or not.

Also to clarify the data points are unique and cannot be repeated. My example has some repeats because I was just smashing the keyboard.

Comment: If your data is indeed random, there is no faster way to search. You *have* to visit each node.

Comment: I'm just looking for the name of an algorithm that searches through random data points to find one specific one. How my code is should be irrelevant.

Comment: Have you considered experimenting with doing it in parallel? e.g. [`concurrent.futures`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) for Python 3 or [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) for Python 2.[67]. (However, there is likely to be significant overhead due large amounts of data transfered.)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, that's what I was afraid of so I just wanted to post here and check.

Comment: If you use sets, rather than lists searching would be way faster, and if you need the ordering lists give, then make a copy of your structure that uses sets just for searching.

Comment: Also; what constitutes a "hit"? That the id is indeed present? A set of indices to where the id is located? A count of ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest search through random data is linear. Pretending your data isn't nested, it's still random, so even flattening it won't help.

To decrease the time complexity, you can increase the space complexity -- keep a dict containing IDs as keys and whatever information you want (possibly a list of indices pointing to the list containing the ID at each level), and update it every time you create/update/delete an element.